# Which jUnit jar file supports Struts2?

Tags: struts2, junit4

I am using Struts 2.0 for my project. I want to do Junit testing. Which `jar` file should I use for this. Can i use Struts test? Currently, I was trying to use struts Junit plugin but it always show exception for Spring framework `NoClassDefFoundError`, but I am not using Spring in my project. What should I do?

I am getting this error, when I am extending `StrutsTestCase`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext
at org.apache.struts2.util.StrutsTestCaseHelper.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCaseHelper.java:48)
at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.initDispatcher(StrutsTestCase.java:45)
at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.setUp(StrutsTestCase.java:41)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this plugin, as it depends on Spring, as you can clearly see. [Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-junit-plugin/2.3.20) you can see its dependencies. Use the official `junit` library. For example, if you are using Maven, you just need to define [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12) dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven:

- You really should :)
- Use [this link](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install) to get JUnit.

---

#### Using the `struts2-junit-plugin` with Maven

If you want to test your Actions using JUnit, you should depend on this Maven artifact

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.20</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This way, when you are testing, all your necessary jars are in place. Because the scope is set to test, the plugin and its dependecies are only used in testing time. Your final application `jar`/`war` won't contain these - neither are the test classes.

Comment: Thank you so much But my project is having jsp and Action Class so i need to give input to the action class through struts.xml for that i would need this plugin.Is there any link where i can get such tutorials .. am really stuck with this .

Comment: If you need this functionality, then you will need to get your dependecy jars. I really suggest using Maven, it will download all the necessary jars. And you can skip the jars used for testing in normal builds too.

Comment: where is this getActionProxy(); method I am not getting this in eclipse

Comment: You should extend `StrutsJUnit4TestCase` instead of `StrutsTestCase`, as the latter is for JUnit 3.

Comment: after  extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase i am getting a compilation error --->The type com.opensymphony.xwork2.XWorkJUnit4TestCase cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: What is your Struts version?

Comment: struts version is 2.0

Comment: The full version, including the minor version.

Comment: Wow, that is really old, you might consider ditching it, as it has tons of security holes. It won't work with JUnit4, you need an older version for it.